# Rolling back code from .net 4.0 to .net 3.5 and now dynamics dont work

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, dynamic, .net-4.0

I have used the KEYWORD dynamic and it is only available in .net 4.0 but I have to roll-back to a .net 3.5 server. I can not use KEYWORD dynamic anymore and need to convert it to work with .net 3.5.  I have a class, FBWeird,that I thought I could cast against but it doesn't work when I put it in fb.Query(query). I use this same method when I rolled back a .Get statement and .Get(id) works for me but not in this instance. Can anyone help me with the below code to get it back working?

### CODE

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient(accessToken.ToString());
var fbResults = fb.Query("SELECT like_count,normalized_url FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.facebook.com/cocacola");
long likeCount = fbResults.like_count;
Response.Write(fbResults.ToString());
```

### CLASS

```
public class FBWeird
{
    public string like_count { get; set; }
}
```

### EDIT

Ok, so some down-voting doubters, for some reason, went all weird on my question.  So.. for the doubters, this is what how you do it:

```
        List<FBWeird> entities = (List<FBWeird>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fbResults.ToString(), typeof(List<FBWeird>));
        foreach (FBWeird obj in entities)
        {
            thisLikeCount = obj.like_count;
        }
```

Output that however you want and it works awesome.

Comment: "but it doesn't work." - what is the error?

Comment: if you are mentioning about the keyword `dynamic` then its a C#4.0 feature

Comment: @Mitch - I don't know where to put it to make it work.

Comment: @John - I want to access the fbResults.like_count LIKE a dynamic without using a dynamic.  I have similar code for a .Get<Fbuser>(id) but it won't let me cast .Query<FBWeird>(Query).

Comment: @naveen - yes. That is what I am trying to convert backwards. Please provide a code example.

Comment: @CSSHell: it might help if we knew what type `fb.Query` returned.

Comment: [{"like_count":"31661080","normalized_url":"http://www.facebook.com/cocacola"}]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're using the Facebook C# SDK. The SDK has two solutions in it - one for 4.0 and one for 3.5. Load the 3.5 solution and compile it and use that DLL instead. Is that what you did to fix it?

Comment: No. I went way back. I actually searched the string returned and grabbed what I needed. Thank you for your understanding of my issue.